# How do you install npm for Windows?

Tags: python, django, terminal, tailwind-css

I am trying to install tailwind CSS, and one of the codes I need to write is the following:

```
$ npm init -y && npm install tailwindcss autoprefixer clean-css-cli && npx tailwindcss init -p
```

However, this is obviously for the macOS. Is there another way to do this for the windows system? Thank you, and please ask me any questions you have.

Comment: On nodejs.org you can download Node with npm for windows. Then you can run the code you posted in cmd. I think people down vote due to you saying it's "obviously" for MacOS, helps to be humble :)

Comment: I current have an app for django in a virtual environment. Would I have to put the downloaded Node in the virtual environment as well? I'm new to coding, so I don't know a lot of things about this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by virtual environment. Are you using docker? A virtual machine? You need node if you want to run npm

Comment: Well... you generally create a virtual env to isolate your django project from the computer right? So, my worry is that when I upload my django website online, the downloaded Node will not be uploaded with the website if it is not in the same virtual env. Then, all of my tailwind css won't work when it is actually online, right?

Comment: Never used Django, sorry. But it seems to be an alternative to Node + npm. So you either use Django + their package manager or Node + npm. Not sure if npm makes sense at all in a Django env. I migh be wrong though.

Comment: Suggest you use a version manager if you're installing npm/node for the first time ... https://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/installing/using-a-node-version-manager.html

Comment: Also, node and django are entirely seperate. In this case you need node for tailwind, though only if you're doing something more complicated with it than just using their css files from the CDN. If you're only doing that, you can skip node :)

Comment: @michjnich Oh wait, I thought that using CDN was unstable because the design of my website could change as Tailwind css updates itself. Since most people (including the Tailwind website) said that it is not recommended to use CDN while in production and in deployment, I thought that using CDN could potentially change my website design if there was a future update in the code definitions. So you are saying the only drawback of using CDN is just that I can't do more complicated tasks? Is it okay to use CDN when I deploy my website online?

Comment: If that's your only concern you can usually pin it to a specific version of the CSS.